# Parse external document and current element in a consistent way with HXT

Tags: xml, haskell, io, arrows

**Update:** I've now solved my main issue so I'll award the bounty to a good review of if my solution is good style or not.

Recently I've been trying to parse [TMX](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format) files, which are XML files describing maps. One interesting point in the format is that you can specify external tilesets.

Since it already handled a big part of the work, I've been trying to extend the [`htiled`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/htiled) library so that it handles external tilesets, but so far with no success.

So basically, the task I'm trying to accomplish here is, given two documents, `map.tmx`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="12" height="12" tilewidth="64" tileheight="64">
 <tileset firstgid="1" source="ground.tsx"/>
 ...
</map>
```

and `ground.tsx`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tileset name="ground" tilewidth="64" tileheight="64" spacing="32">
 <image source="ground.png" width="64" height="64"/>
 <tile id="0">
  <properties>
   <property name="sol" value=""/>
  </properties>
 </tile>
</tileset>
```

return the structure:

```
Map {..., tilesets = [Tileset { name = "ground", ...}]}
```

The working method to parse (internal only) tilesets is:

```
tilesets ∷ IOSArrow XmlTree [Tileset]
tilesets = listA tileset

tileset ∷ IOSArrow XmlTree Tileset
tileset = isElem >>> hasName "tileset" >>> proc ts → do
  tsName        ← getAttrValue "name"                        ⤙ ts
  tsInitialGid  ← getAttrR "firstgid"                        ⤙ ts
  tsTileWidth   ← getAttrR "tilewidth"                       ⤙ ts
  tsTileHeight  ← getAttrR "tileheight"                      ⤙ ts
  tsMargin      ← arr (fromMaybe 0) . getAttrMaybe "margin"  ⤙ ts
  tsSpacing     ← arr (fromMaybe 0) . getAttrMaybe "spacing" ⤙ ts
  tsImages      ← images                                     ⤙ ts
  tsTileProperties ← listA tileProperties                    ⤙ ts
  returnA ⤙ Tileset {..}
  where tileProperties ∷ IOSArrow XmlTree (Word32, Properties)
        tileProperties = getChildren >>> isElem >>> hasName "tile"
                     >>> getAttrR "id" &&& properties
        images = listA (getChildren >>> image)
```

I've tried to adapt the `tilesets` method so that it uses the current element or an external document depending on the `source` attribute of the current element, but to no avail:

```
tilesets ∷ IOSArrow XmlTree [Tileset]
tilesets = listA $ proc ts → do
  source ← isElem >>> hasName "tileset" >>> getAttrValue "source" ⤙ ts
  case source of
    "" → tileset ⤙ ts
    f → tileset ⤙ readDocument [withValidate no, withWarnings yes] f
```

(this is one of my many attempts).

Usually I reach a point where GHC tells me that I'm not using an arrow command or that my value is inside an arrow while it shouldn't. I get that I can't do IO (and maybe also XHT intermediate operations?) transparently in a type safe way but I'm stuck here. I'm really unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work with `readFromDocument` and `ifA`

```
tilesets ∷ FilePath → IOSArrow XmlTree [Tileset]
tilesets mapPath =
  listA $ getChildren >>> isElem >>> hasName "tileset"
  >>> getAttrR "firstgid" &&& ifA (hasAttr "source") (externalTileset mapPath) id
  >>> tileset

externalTileset ∷ FilePath → IOSArrow XmlTree XmlTree
externalTileset mapPath =
  arr (const (dropFileName mapPath)) &&& getAttrValue "source"
  >>> arr (uncurry (</>))
  >>> readFromDocument [ withValidate no, withWarnings yes ]
  >>> getChildren >>> isElem >>> hasName "tileset"

tileset ∷ IOSArrow (Word32, XmlTree) Tileset
tileset = proc (tsInitialGid, ts) → do
  tsName           ← getAttrValue "name"                        ⤙ ts
  tsTileWidth      ← getAttrR "tilewidth"                       ⤙ ts
  tsTileHeight     ← getAttrR "tileheight"                      ⤙ ts
  tsMargin         ← arr (fromMaybe 0) . getAttrMaybe "margin"  ⤙ ts
  tsSpacing        ← arr (fromMaybe 0) . getAttrMaybe "spacing" ⤙ ts
  tsImages         ← images                                     ⤙ ts
  tsTileProperties ← listA tileProperties                       ⤙ ts
  returnA ⤙ Tileset {..}
  where tileProperties ∷ IOSArrow XmlTree (Word32, Properties)
        tileProperties = getChildren >>> isElem >>> hasName "tile"
                         >>> getAttrR "id" &&& properties
        images = listA (getChildren >>> image)
```